# Why is it so hard to get your own local IP address

Tags: ip, network-interface, ifconfig

There are *so many* questions asking basically: how do I get my local IP address? None of answers are portable, they all seem like a hack. This seems like such a common need, but there are no good solutions. Why? Why can't we have a nice Unix tool that simply does this? Is this actually a hard problem?

Comment: It is not unix-related, it is how network works - you can be behind router on local network, and your computer doesn't know what its outside address is. What you need is just parameters of this local network and all packages from/to your computer are just forwarded by the router.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you consider `ip a` hacky? It shows you all of the information you need to know about any of your network interfaces at a glance.

How about `ifconfig`?

`hostname -I`?

Comment: None of those are portable across systems? With ip addr you have to parse the output for the results, which changes with versions of IP. hostname -I is not on my machine. Neither is ifconfig.